# Closing questions because answers are off-topic

Tags: discussion, flags, vote-to-close, close-reasons, off-topic

Usually one asks for closing questions that appear off-topic. But what about questions with *answers* off-topic?

It happened few times that I've asked a specific question and I've received a lot of comments like: "why you don't do this other way?", or "I have so many experience and I wouldn't do things like this", etc...

They might are precious hints, indeed, but in the same way a question that asks for personal-based opinions will be immediately flagged and closed, why this doesn't happen for un-requested personal-based opinions answers?

It seems the only possibility is to delete my own question.

As an example:

I [asked](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/74050/9033) how to reduce the boot time of a PC. I received some comments about keeping the PC always powered on... you understand this doesn't answer to the question at all.

Comment: So, "you are doing it wrong" is not a valid answer?

Comment: Not in all contexts. Sometimes it's just a workaround that doesn't fit the question at all.

Comment: Example: I asked how to reduce the boot time of a PC. I received some comments about keeping the PC always powered on... you understand this doesn't answer to the question at all.

Comment: Can you specifically link to some examples of this?

Comment: @Catija I hope this is allowed: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/74050/9033

Comment: Please note, comments are not answers. I don't have an account there but, as of right now, you don't have any answers. We do like questions to be clear, so if you could explain why rebooting is necessary, that would clarify your question for other users who may be interested in helping you with this concern. All of the responses in your comments add detail and explain why this is a problem. It's valuable information.

Comment: @Catija thanks for your advice. I updated the question trying to better explain the scenario.

Comment: @Mark - Your question is based on questions that have received an answer, the one example you submitted in a comment (not the question body), was a question that has received no answers.  *I don't even know what your question is exactly.*  You have received feedback on this question, you choose to reply to that feedback, with a comment instead of improving the question.  You indicated you updated the question, but you have made zero edits to this question, so it isn't clear what you are referring to.

Comment: @Ramhound Um... The question on Raspberry Pi **was** edited... six hours ago. My comment about comments above was about the Raspberry Pi question, as was Mark's reply.

Comment: Ok, you're killing my with downvotes. Please close this question. For me comments "are" answers in the meaning of feedbacks from other users. I understand (now) you were looking for actual *answers*, in the SE meaning.

Answer (score 9):

To respond to your broader question - no, we don't **generally** close questions as off topic because they're attracting off topic answers. We judge questions based on the question, not the answers it attracts.

That being said, the accumulation of several "off topic" answers does send up a red flag to us - the question may be unclear or lacking in detail. We do have close reasons for this, so if it seems like you're getting too broad of a solution set, that implies that your question is also too broad.

---

Your specific case. You posted a [question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/74050/9033) on our Rasperry Pi site. Unless there are deleted answers I can't see, you don't **have** any answers. You have comments from a user who is asking for you to explain **why** you need to reboot your system regularly. This is what comments are for - requesting clarification.

All of the information in your comments explaining why you can not leave the system up constantly is important to explain why you're trying to solve the problem that you're solving. One of the concerns we have on Stack Exchange in general is the concept of the "[XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)". You have decided that your problem is that your system takes too long to reboot. But what I think Miliways is trying to figure out is whether the problem isn't really "How can I fix this system so that it doesn't have to reboot so often?" Solving this problem is very different.

If you have a valid explanation for why the system must reboot regularly and there's no way around this, then, yes, your question as it stands is probably what you should be trying to solve but, as I noted, explaining why you're stuck having to reboot constantly will make it clear why this is the problem you are trying to solve.

Now, if you think about it more and realize, you know, maybe I do need to figure out how to prevent the system from needing to reboot so often - you need a different question and solution.

Answer (score 3):

I think its one of those cases where the common sense rule comes into place.

Firstly, I'd ask myself if the question is *on topic*. In the example given - it certainly is.

Secondly, looking at any answers (there's none yet), I'd try to understand the confusion, and why off topic answers are being posted - there's none at this point.

Comments are sometimes handy when people want clarification, and in this case, there's someone wondering "Why not leave this low power design on" - and trying to work out if its an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). To me, it feels borderline. Boot time profiling is actually pretty common, and there's many situations where fast booting is handy. I'd consider explaining why an *addition* that would make it a better question, rather than essential.

So... there's no real reason to consider the question off topic, and the *comments* don't really reflect on much more than one approach which isn't considered in your question. OP realises that, else they'd post an answer. Clarifications are a nice way to improve (and bump) your question the right way and there's no real reason to close the question. Even the "off topic" comments are pretty pi specific, since there would be other approaches for other machines (like sleep)

Answer (score 2):

Every user posting an answer will try to post the best answer possible. If the best possible answer is: *you shouldn't do it this way but I have a better option*, I would love such an answer.

As long as the answer actually answers the question posted, it is okay. If you don't like it and instead want to fix your broken solution, it is your choice. Downvote the post if you deem it 'not useful' and move on. Others will upvote though since they want the actual best answer (in their opinion).

And maybe you will receive an answer that does fit you, although it is not the best answer possible.

---

To go with your example:

> I asked how to reduce the boot time of a PC. I received some comments about keeping the PC always powered on... you understand this doesn't answer to the question at all.

So if the answer is: don't turn it off but put it in sleep mode, which saves 99% of the energy, isn't a valid answer just because the computer is not entirely off?

You are limiting yourself in possible answers if you take the boundaries to literal. Often very useful solutions come up when you look just a little further. But indeed, totally off-topic answers should be downvoted since they don't answer the question.

Comment: I agree, but if I explicitly say this isn't an alternative (i.e. due to project constraints) I think is useless to say "remove that constraint". I  hope you understand what I mean - my English is not so good.

Comment: That might be a useful answer if you have the influence to change it or you can talk to the person who can. @Mark

Comment: @Mark the point being someone having the same problem but not the ame constraint could find the answer useful. we're building a collection of Q/A and not an individually tailored support forum.

Comment: Well, I see how different is how point of view. Good! In my opinion if I ask for a specific question, that is not a valid answer. Instead you could say: "No, you *can't* do this hence I suggest you another way". But proposing an alternative *without* arguments what's wrong in my question is not so useful.

Comment: @Tensibai The point of SO as a reference is that people can find questions and then *answers to those questions*.  Having answers that don't answer the question asked aren't helpful, as the people that have the question answered won't be able to find it.  If there's a solution that you think would be helpful then you should be posting that as a solution for a question that it's the answer to.

Comment: @Servy That's what I'm saying, a valid answer not practical to the op could be practical to someone else, if a valid answer is "you can do that in java9 this way and it's more straightforward" but op can't  upgrade to java9 right now, that's still a valid answer even if not useful for the Q author. Another reader passing by could upgrade and find it useful. As far as it address the problem, even not taking in account a roadblock, it could be useful IMHO.

Comment: @Tensibai If a question asks how to solve a problem in Java 7, then the question should be answered as to how to solve the problem in Java 7.  That way people looking for the solution to the problem using Java 7 can find that solution.  If someone wants to know how to solve the problem in Java 9 (or without any constraints on what version they can use) then they can ask *that* question.  Posting an answer that doesn't actually answer the question isn't helpful as a future resource for other people with that same question.

Comment: @PatrickHofman: I'm sorry but I disagree. Putting it in sleep mode doesn't answer to the question "how to reduce the **boot** time" because it actually doesn't boot at all. I will accept it as a valid answer if you tell me that **I cannot** reduce further my boot time. It's not matter of limiting myself, just to be coherent on what is asked.

Comment: @servy the example may be extreme with java version, another try: in R a question asking how to do something with dplyr could benefit a lot of answer using data tables or tidyverse

Comment: @Tensibai I'm not familiar with those topics, so I couldn't comment on them.  But if a question's answers would be useful to other people *in the same situation that the question describes*, with the same constraints, then that's a good answer, even if the answer is something like, "there is no solution to that problem unless you can remove one of those constraints".  Of course, if the OP has constraints *not mentioned in the question* then there's no requirement for an answer to consider them.  It's the OP's responsibility to ensure the question accurately describes their problem.

Comment: @Servy I fully agree, but I think an answer not applicable due to OP's constraint can still be useful to another person with different constraints but a similar problem. It won't usually be the accepted answer but that's not the goal. I sometimes do those kind of answers (specially on configuration management things), stating that's an alternative or just an exemple of a method in another tool because I'm more familiar with it.

Comment: @Tensibai You don't post Java answers to a C++ question because, "A Java developer might just happen to come across this C++ question and want the solution for the problem in Java".  If someone is in a different situation than the question describes, then there should be a different question for that situation.  If you, as a Java developer, come across that C++ question and feel that SO needs a Java solution, then post your solution *to a question asking how to solve that problem in Java* (even if you have to write it yourself, if there is no such question already).

Comment: @servy I agree, not all question allow this, some java question tagged spring may be answered with grails and still be useful (let's say: "How to validate a date field in java?" for exemple), I won't say all question could fit, a lot just don't allow useful alternatives.